# Deserializing a JSON data file

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I'm struggling to deserialize an input data file in python 2.7 and didn't really know where to start. I saved the input file as JSON:

```
{
    "Group": {
        "Test": {
            "test1": {
                "x1": 100,
                "y1": 150
            },
            "test2": {
                "x1": 23,
                "y1": 56,
                "x2": 200,
                "y2": 234
            },
            "test3": {
                "x1": 123,
                "y1": 456,
                "x2": 345,
                "y2": 986,
                "x3": 234,
                "y3": 654
            },
            "test4": {
                "x1": 789,
                "y1": 987,
                "x2": 345,
                "y2": 555,
                "x3": 111,
                "y3": 222,
                "x4": 333,
                "y4": 444
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to strip out the data so if case "test1" is needed I can take the value of x1 and y1 and populate a field. If 3 pairs of x and y values are needed I would need to grab the values from "test3".

I'm trying to populate fields in the following variable in code. It's saved as a dictionary as the end product is a JSON file. I need to populate the width and height fields with the values from the data file listed above. Here is the variable printed out using json.dumps for readability:

```
{
    "subs": {
        "1": {
            "video_info": {
                "width": x1,
                "height": y1
            }
        },
        "2": {
            "video_info": {
                "width": x2,
                "height": y2
            }
        },
        "3": {
            "video_info": {
                "width": x3,
                "height": y3
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above variable was pieced together by pulling data from different objects (each dictionary under "subs") so I can't write the whole thing as a dictionary from scratch. Each item in "subs" already has a width and height value that needs to be overwritten.

Examples of deserialization I've seen all had set keys. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: does not look like valid JSON.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! :) Check your json here first. http://json.parser.online.fr/

Comment: and regardless of that, not clear what you are asking, please provide input/desired output/your code and explain what is not working.

Comment: Sorry about that, wrote something quick and didn't use proper quotes for   JSON. I edited that part and will update the desired result

Comment: You do have set keys... Is the deserializer currently throwing an error? Or are you having difficulty **parsing**? You've tagged the question with Python, so where's the Python code?

Comment: I'm having difficulty parsing. I searched and the examples I saw showed deserializing to an object with set fields. Since some parts of my data file had multiple x or y variables I couldn't use the solution posted to those.

Comment: If you're actually having difficulty parsing the JSON, show us your code. If it's anything more complicated than `json.loads` or `json.load`, whatever extra complexity you've added is the problem, and nobody can debug that code without seeing it.

Answer (score 0):

```
d={
    "Group": {
        "Test": {
            "test1": {
                "x1": 100,
                "y1": 150
            },
            "test2": {
                "x1": 23,
                "y1": 56,
                "x2": 200,
                "y2": 234
            },
            "test3": {
                "x1": 123,
                "y1": 456,
                "x2": 345,
                "y2": 986,
                "x3": 234,
                "y3": 654
            },
            "test4": {
                "x1": 789,
                "y1": 987,
                "x2": 345,
                "y2": 555,
                "x3": 111,
                "y3": 222,
                "x4": 333,
                "y4": 444
            }
        }
    }
}
d2={"subs": {}}
for i in range(1,4):
  s=str(i)
  d2["subs"][s]={}
  t=d2["subs"][s]['video_info']={}
  t['width']=d['Group']['Test'][f'test{i}'][f'x{s}']
  t['height']=d['Group']['Test'][f'test{i}'][f'y{s}']
print(d2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save it to a variable and call over it to see test1-4

```
import json
json_data = json.dumps({
    "Group": {
        "Test": {
            "test1": {
                "x1": 100,
                "y1": 150
            },
            "test2": {
                "x1": 23,
                "y1": 56,
                "x2": 200,
                "y2": 234
            },
            "test3": {
                "x1": 123,
                "y1": 456,
                "x2": 345,
                "y2": 986,
                "x3": 234,
                "y3": 654
            },
            "test4": {
                "x1": 789,
                "y1": 987,
                "x2": 345,
                "y2": 555,
                "x3": 111,
                "y3": 222,
                "x4": 333,
                "y4": 444
            }
        }
    }
})

json = json.loads(json_data)
print json["Group"]["Test"]["test4"]
```